# is there anyone who knows how to fix this error

Tags: python

i'm trying to run this code for my project but its given an error at the try statement i.e "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

DEVELOPER_KEY = "Replaced_my_API_key"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)


  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
      channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
      playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

  print ("Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n")
  print ("Channels:\n", "\n".join(channels), "\n")
  print ("Playlists:\n", "\n".join(playlists), "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_search = "Witcher 3"
    argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=to_search)
    argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", 
default=25)
    args = argparser.parse_args()

  **From the following statement the code is giving an error**
```

i.e "unindent error"
           try:
             youtube_search(args)
           except HttpError, e:
             print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)

Comment: "unindent does not match any outer indentation level" -- The error is self explanatory. Please check indentation and fix it. Python is pretty serious about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This error is common if you are mixing idendation with *spaces* and *tabs*. Choose one and stick to it. You can try two things:

- **Colorize the whitespace in your editor**. In vim you can do this with `:set list`. Find the offending line and correct it.
- Give Python the option **-tt** in the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/python -tt`. This gives you extra warnings when you are mixing identation in the same file.